# Sorting an array based on how well a contained value matches a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, math

**The Scenario**

I have a list of print formats, and an uploaded image.

The image may match certain formats well, and others less.

For instance, if the image is in ratio `4:3`, it will match a format `40 x 30 cm`.

However, there are also formats which do not fit the image exactly, for example: `40 x 35 cm`.

**The Problem**

The formats need to be ordered by how well they fit the image.

**Code**

```
$formats = array(
    '30x40',
    '35x40',
    '40x60'
);

// Ratios in the format (such as 3:4) won't serve us in calculations.
// Therefore we use the images aspect factor, which we compute
// like this:

$imageAspectFactor = $imageX / $imageY;
```

At least that's how i think i could do this.

**Question**

From here on out, i have no idea where to go. Mathematically speaking, how can the aspect factor of the image be matched against the resulting aspect factor of the (current) format (in the loop), so that the resulting value can be used as an array key for building a new, ordered array of formats?

In order to understand this better, see the following, practical code snippet:

**Practical Code**

```
$formats = array(
    '30x40',
    '35x40',
    '40x60'
);

foreach($formats as $formatString){
    list($formatX, $formatY) = explode('x', $formatString);
    $formatAspectFactor = $formatX / $formatY;
    $output[/* NUMERIC THAT REPRESENTS HOW WELL FORMAT MATCHES IMAGE*/] = $formatString;
}

ksort($output);
```

Please take note: i don't need a complete solution, unless you feel overly motivated. What i look for is the mathematical understanding of how to calculate how well a number matches another one, and represent this, somehow, in a numeric.

Comment: Just order them by the difference between the image’s and the format’s aspect ratio quotient …? The lower the (absolute) difference, the better the match – no?

Comment: _“so that the resulting value can be used as an array key for building a new, ordered array of formats?”_ – that is not recommendable however; should two formats match the image equally well, then you would probably override an array element. Stop trying to sort this by array keys – you want to sort by values, not keys.

Comment: @CBRoe Wow, is it that simple? I shall try that. Very good point regard the keys and the overwriting. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll adapt the code.